# How were branch instructions implemented on 6502 microcprocessor?

Tags: microcontroller, hardware, instructions, decoder, 6502

There are a lot of ways how to implement a branch instruction into the controller/sequencer hardware. I have done it myself before with my own method, but my question is: how was it done on the 6502 microprocessor and is there a universtal or at least a popular way of designing hardware for branch instructions?

(Additional information) The method I used was I added flags pins attached to opcode bus that when set high during specific branch instruction would load the value of specific flag into the decoder ROM, thus executing branch if flag was high/low and skipping branch if flag was low/high. For example, during BNE (Branch on Not Equal) intruction, on specific clock cycle the "Zero flag" pin would be activated. If the pin is low, then it doesen't change the opcode and the decoder normally goes to next memory location to execute next microinstruction set which in this case is ending BNE instruction without branching and then waiting for new instruction. However, if the "Zero flag" pin is high then it changes the opcode, thus making decoder skip to the new address (which is equal to opcode) where it will read a different set of microinstructions which will execute the branch instead of just ending/ignoring it.

Comment: are you making a 6502 clone or making a processor in general.  the 6502 isnt bad but is it really what you want to model yours from?  There is no right answer obviously and it depends on the instruction set, for example an arm you have multiple program counters the fake one used in math with r15, the one actually prefetching at a minimum.  If your instruction set doesnt have an exposed program counter then it depends on how you compute pc relative addressing, relative branches and possibly relative data accesses as to whether you can use a single pc for that and fetching.

Comment: you look at a 6502 or other in that era and they would appear to have a single program counter that does the fetching and when you get to execution is pointing at the next instruction.  if I remember my 6502  correctly.  Remember these chips were drawn by hand on paper, every transistor.    lean and mean

Comment: as pointed out the visual6502 folks have learned an aweful lot from reverse engineering for whatever reason you are interested in the 6502 that is a good resource.  note there are 6502 open cores out there you can download and examine as well...

Comment: I wouldnt change the opcode I would have a state machine and state variables.  unless there are enough free opcodes left in the chart to cover these states you want to change to.

Comment: @old_timer I'm not trying to make an exact replica of 6502, I just want to build a processor that will work the same way. I'm doing all of that in a simulator (Logisim), not in real life. I haven't heared of opencores, will check out 6502 on their site once my registering there is complete. Haven't heared of state machines and variables either.
I suppose I'll just make the branching hardware/software the best way I can think of.

Comment: open cores in general some are at opencores.org, you get what you pay for with an open core remember.  and there are others not on that site but just out in the wild, maybe github, etc

Comment: you basically have to deal with, fetching using some address, and computing branch destinations using some address as a reference point.  then conditional branches which can product two possible results and/or you modify the pc or dont dpeneding on the condition.  you can have your logic compute the possible destination whether or not the condition passes, but ultimately you should have an if-then-else  if condition then pc=pc_computed, else pc=pc kind of thing.  being logic, something programmable, logic, software, whatever you are of course free to design it and implement it however you like

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the opcode does not change, ever.

Unless you have insider information about the 6502's "microcode" you can't possibly know the exact implementation.  A datasheet only gives you the operation that is performed, but it rarely gives details as to how exactly this is accomplished.  One can only guess.

One such guess:

1. The corresponding Condition Code Register bit (normal or inverted depending on the instruction) masks the branch instruction operand to zero if the branch should not be taken.
2. The (now possibly masked) 8-bit signed offset is added to the PC.

Comment: Comprehensive "insider" information can be found at the [Visual 6502](http://www.visual6502.org/welcome.html) website.  Especially useful for deriving from first principles an answer to this specific question might be Beregnyei Balazs's [reverse engineered schematic](http://www.visual6502.org/wiki/index.php?title=Balazs%27_schematic_and_documents).

Comment: So, you're saying branch instructions use offsets to branch to the needed memory location? I was thinking it works more like jump instruction: you write the absolute address and it gets loaded into PC if the branch is taken. Nevertheless, I explained my method very poorly and complicated, I might edit it. I designed my microcontroller such that it changes the opcode of mid-processed branch instruction if the branch should be taken and doesen't change it if the branch should not be taken. It works like a branch within a branch instruction. I haven't heared of Condition Code Register.

Comment: Condition Code Register is one of many possible names for the register that keeps the various CPU flags.  I don't remember what the 6502 name was (maybe status register?).  Branch instructions use signed offsets (normally, 8-bit in the smaller and older CPUs but it could be any size depending on the CPU).  The offset is normally from the instruction following the branch as the PC is always incremented to point past the current instruction.  You can have any implementation you like but preferrably instructions have fixed number of execution cycles regardless of flow of internal execution.

Comment: On the 6502 it's the status register or the flags register. Known as 'P' for Processor [status/flags]. I feel like CCR as a term most strongly associates with the 68000, but that's not something I'd care to try to evidence. Alas I'm a dunce as to the now-known internals of the 6502, so I've nothing more helpful to add.

Comment: I see, Condition Code Register is the same register as Processor Status Register (flags register). I'm still currious how these branch instructions are usually implemented into processors. Also, using offsets instead of absolute addresses seems inefficient to me. Why is it better than absolute addressing?

Comment: Branches are actually very efficient.  Their main advantages are shorter instructions (2-byte BRA versus 3-byte JMP in 8-bit machines), and position-independence which is needed when the same code is loaded at different addresses under an OS.  Some CPUs (e.g., 6809) include long branches (e.g., LBRA) with 16bit offset.

Comment: @Senijs On the 6502 branches are calculated by sign extending the eight bit offset and adding it to the PC (which, at this point is two bytes beyond the address of the branch instruction).

Comment: Note that the address calculation uses the 8-bit ALU to add the sign-extended 8-bit offset to the 16-bit PC - and so if the branch crosses a page boundary (i.e. generates a carry from the lower 8 bits to the upper 8 bits) an additional cycle is required to increment or decrement the upper half of the PC.  (Alternatively stated, the 8-bit ALU requires 2 cycles to perform a 16-bit addition, but the sequencer short-circuits this if there's no carry from the lower half.)